# Merging Excel cells in between two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am Working with many Excel files. The first column is fixed with the heading `product-name`. The other column name is `price`.

I am trying to merge the columns that are between these two columns, Each file contains different number of columns between these two columns `product-name and price`

I am having trouble writing a macro to run each Excel file, can anyone show me an example?

Comment: Whats wrong with my question. lol

Comment: Show us your code :)

Comment: @Omar - that sounds suspiciously like something a bouncer at a biker bar would say.

Comment: @Omar I dont have code as I dont know how to deal with this problem. But I can show you what exactly I want. Suppose I have 1 excel file with 5 columns. The first column heading is Product-name and the 5th column heading is price. I want to merge the 2-3-4 columns and put them in center of column 1 and 5. This is for my 1 excel file. I have 100 excel files which may have 10 columns also (8 column between product-name and price). I want a VBA script that runs for every excel file. Thank you. I hope you get my question :)

Comment: @Nandish, you need to show some effort. What did you try? Where is your code going wrong? You really can't expect us to just do your job...

Comment: @vacip: - I said I am new to VBA and also I dont know how to deal with this problem. Thanks for reading my question :)

Comment: @Nandish, I'm really sorry, but SO is not a free code writing service. You will have to learn to write VBA code, and we will be happy to help if you get stuck somewhere. Or alternatively you can hire a professional to write the macro for you.

Comment: I dont want you to write the Macro code for me. I was looking for proper way to deal with this question. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Oh well, you will need to loop through the rows, and merge all the cells between your beginning and ending coloumns. There is no fast or easy way I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay Let me try that. I am scared because I have around 200-300 thousand rows in every excel file. Will let you know if I am struck. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that only 1 st row need to be checked. assuming these are headers.

You can use the below VBA to check the the column headers and merge the in between columns

I have used random variables, you may change accordingly.

```
Sub test() 
    Cells(1, 1).Select 
    j = 1 
Do
    k = Cells(1, j).Value
    Cells(1, j).Select
    j = j + 1
Loop Until (k = "Product-name")
c1 = j
Do
    k = Cells(1, j).Value
    Cells(1, j).Select
    j = j + 1
Loop Until (k = "Price")
c2 = j - 2
If (c2 > c1) Then
    Range(Columns(c1), Columns(c2)).Select
    Selection.Merge
End If
End Sub
```

k variable will store the column value and will be compared to "`Product-name`" and "`Price`".
c1 will store the next column number of the "`Product-name`" 
c2 will store the column number of the "`Price`" -1, in logic it advances by 2 so subtracting the column number with 2.

Now you have column numbers in between both the headers.

Here there is small scenario which need to be considered, if there are no columns or if there is at least one column between these 2 columns, in that case directly you cannot merge columns. so additional comparison of column values.

I hope this answers your query. The code is tested and is working fine.

Comment: I think your question can be removed from "On hold".
Omar : Thanks for editing the format.
@Nandish: I think your requirement is fulfilled. Just make sure you don't have extra spaces on the cells with "Product-name" and "Price". otherwise the code will run infinitely. Also the order of the header should be "Product-name" and "Price".